# Get value of string between two <a> tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to take this:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a>
```

and have it return

```
email@email.com
```

And I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this? I'm really horrible with regex but I'm pretty sure I just need to find `">` and get what comes between that and `</a>` but I'm not sure how to search for the thing between two other things.

**edit:** I actually found the regex I need: `.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'')` to strip the tags away and give the inner contents, but the solutions down below are probably the better way to do it. Thanks guys!

Comment: is this the only `<a>` tag on the page?

Comment: Nope, there are quite a few. I'm getting the innerHTML of the element that contains the <a> </a> though.

Comment: thats what I'm asking. If this is the only <a> tag it could be done using `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: I would be better if you show us some more code so we can easily get to this specific <a> tag, not any <a> tag

Comment: Any reason you can't assign an ID to this tag for easy grabbing?

Answer (score 2):

If a single `<a>` tag on html then use,

`document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;`

If there are multiple `<a>` tags try giving them IDs

`<a href="mailto:email@email.com" id="someID">email@email.com</a>`

then in javascript:-

`document.getElementByID("someID").innerHTML;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0;i<a.length;i++) {
  console.log(a[i].getAttribute('href').replace('mailto:',''))
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:email1@email.com">email@email.com</a>
<a href="mailto:email2@email.com">email@email.com</a>
<a href="mailto:email3@email.com">email@email.com</a>
<a href="mailto:email4@email.com">email@email.com</a>
<a href="mailto:email5@email.com">email@email.com</a>
```

Comment: You could get the content of <a> tag, so you don't need to remove 'mailto:'

Comment: True @AkiraYamamoto, but I wasn't sure if the innerHTML will really be the full email address.

Answer (score 1):

If your A tag is a DOM node:

```
<a id="test" href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a>

<script>
console.log(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
</script>
```

If this is a string on the server side:

```
$str='<a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a>';
echo strip_tags($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility...

**HTML**

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a>
<a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">email@gmail.com</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   alert(a[i].getAttribute('href').split(':')[1]);
}
```

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brv3kjvq/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery it's quite simple:

```
$("a[href^='mailto']").html();
```

And if you have more than one mailto link:

```
$.each($("a[href^='mailto']"), function( index, element ) {
  console.log($(element).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for multiple  elements

```
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach( (e) => {
    console.log(e.textContent);
});
```